# How to match words with common prefix in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, string-matching

I need to write a regex to match the word. To find exact word can be done using `/\bword\b/` pattern.

But I want the pattern to find `word`, `words`, `wording` and so on.

for example i want to write a pattern to find terms `account`, `accounting`, `accounts` and `accountant` in a paragraph string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To just match your keyword optionally followed by `s`, `ing`, `ant`, you can use:

```
/\b($word(?:|s|ing|ant))\b/i
```

[**see it**](http://www.ideone.com/GlIUE)

If you want to allow any optional letters as suffix you can use:

```
/\b($word\w*)\b/i
```

Comment: the second one for any variation worked for me. thanks.
@andread \w was missing instead of . in your pattern, anyways thanks again to all

Comment: @daron: You are welcome. Also since you are new to SO, I would like to tell you that you can accept the answer that helped you the most by clicking on the right mark next to the answer :)

Comment: how to use the same expression for mysql. I tried  

SELECT * FROM table WHERE word REGEXP '/\b($word\w*)\b/i';  

this didn't worked

Answer (score 1):

I think this gets you there:

```
/\<word(|s|ing)\>/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\b(accounting|accounts|account)\b
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I don't think `"/\b*word*\b/"` gets word, instead it actually matches things like `'''''wor'` or `||worddddd|`, if you want word and its variant, try:

```
/\bword[^\b]+\b/i
```

Comment: ignore those * i was actually trying to bold the word.
your solution instead of looking for a word actually matched everything after the first match for word.

Comment: `[^\b]` won't work - `\b` is not interpreted as a word boundary inside a character class. The negation of `\b` is `\B`, but even this won't work here - it doesn't make any sense to repeat a zero-length assertion, and of course it will never be possible to match a `\b` right after a `\B`.